# need to alter slider with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple slider that I want to show images to the left and right of the default image and scroll left and right with buttons.

current setup: [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/cwilliams23/pen/DBjkC)

Below is my code for sliding the images but it only works correctly when they slide from right to left, how do I get it to work when sliding from left to right and have images on the left be visible before sliding?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#btnRight").click(function(){
$('#carousel ul').animate({marginLeft:'-=810px'}, 1000, function(){

    $(this).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
    $(this).css({marginLeft:0});
});
});
});

$(document).ready(function() {

$("#btnLeft").click(function(){
$('#carousel ul').animate({marginLeft:'+=810px'}, 1000, function(){

    $(this).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
    $(this).css({marginLeft:0});
});
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnRight").click(function(){
    $('#carousel ul').animate({marginLeft:'-=810px'}, 1000, function(){
        $(this).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
        $(this).css({marginLeft:0});
    });
  });
  $("#btnLeft").click(function(){
    $('#carousel ul li:first').before($("#carousel ul").find("li:last"));
    $('#carousel ul').css({"margin-left":"-810px"});
    $('#carousel ul').animate({marginLeft:'+=810px'}, 1000, function(){
        $(this).css({marginLeft:0});
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly for scrolling to the left, thank you. Do you know if it's possible to shift this to the left 810px so that the images to the left and right are visible?